# Should we have tags for Pie-Menus?

Tags: discussion, tags

Pie-Menus are well implemented now and finding their way into daily workflows with Blender. Should we create a [pie-menus](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pie-menus) tag or a [pie-menu](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pie-menu) tag at least, even if they are rather specific?

From the [Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/UI/Pie_Menus):

> A pie menu is a menu whose items are spread radially around the mouse.

Comment: +1 from me. From [a quick estimate](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+pie+menus) we have maybe ~20-30 questions which could use this tag.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm working on a *big* retag (will be on meta) and had already included this in it. (so yes I support it.)

Comment: @David Thanks for your opinion. You are the tag guru, then we should wait for your proposal :) I assume it's hard work to re-tag the questions, so let me know if I can help to edit the posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think so. I don't know how many questions we've got for them so far, but they do have special code api's and stuff, so there's definitely room for coding questions.